# clojure rest and next related

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation, lazy-sequences

I was following *The Joy of Clojure* and I am puzzled with these 2 statements

```
(def very-lazy (-> (iterate #(do (print \.) (inc %)) 1) rest rest rest))

(def less-lazy (-> (iterate #(do (print \.) (inc %)) 1) next next next))
```

accordingly, the output was

```
(println (first very-lazy)) ; .4

(println (first less-lazy)) ; 4
```

The book continued to explain that

> Grabbing the first element in a lazy seq built with rest causes a
>   realization as expected. But the same doesn’t happen for a seq built
>   with next because it’s already been previously realized. Using next
>   causes a lazy seq to be one element less lazy, which might not be
>   desired if the cost of realization is expensive.

My burning question is why there is an extra dot for 'very-lazy'? My thought was 'print' would print its argument when invoked regardless if `next` or `rest`.

Thanks

Comment: On a related note, next and rest behave differently on the empty list. (rest '()) returns the empty list. (next '()) returns nil. So next is useful in nil punning situations when doing recursion especially. What I cannot figure out is if the difference in laziness between next and rest is a consequence of this fact, or independent from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing something important. Count the dots:

```
user> (def very-lazy (-> (iterate #(do (print \.) (inc %)) 1) rest rest rest))
..#'user/very-lazy

user> (def less-lazy (-> (iterate #(do (print \.) (inc %)) 1) next next next))
...#'user/less-lazy
```

It always helps to run the code for real instead of just reading a book.

Comment: +1, and it will be more expressive if slightly change the function: `#(do (print %) (inc %))`

Comment: tat what I missed. I missed those dots. now I get the examples.

Answer (score 7):

Print actually did exactly the same thing in both cases, it printed only the number. The extra `.` was printed by the code inside the list, it just happened to occur at the same time as the printing of the `4` and so it ended up next to it on the screen.

the extra dot is **a side effect of the lazy sequence being created on the fly**. I would propose a more verbose example to clarify this:

start with two identical lists, both fully-lazy:

```
esc.core=> (def a (iterate #(do (print "making new element") (inc %)) 1)) 
#'esc.core/a
esc.core=> (def b (iterate #(do (print "making new element") (inc %)) 1))
#'esc.core/b
```

then make two more identical lists that start on the fourth element of `a` and `b` respectively

```
esc.core=> (def a-partially-realized (-> a rest rest rest))
making new elementmaking new element#'esc.core/a-partially-realised
esc.core=> (def b-more-fully-realized (-> b next next next))
making new elementmaking new elementmaking new element#'esc.core/b-more-fully-realised
esc.core=>
```

the first **three** elements of `a-partially-realized` have been pre-computed
while the first **four** elements of `b-more-fully-realized` have been pre-computed.

when we read the first element (the fourth in the original list) of `a-partially-realized` it has not yet been computed so we will see it being computed.

```
esc.core=> (print (first a-partially-realized))
making new element4nil
```

when we do the same to `b-more-fully-realised` it will already have the value cached so we just get the result immediately.

```
esc.core=> (print (first b-more-fully-realized))
4nil
```

Answer (score 4):

As Joost points out, the magic happens when you define very-lazy and less-lazy.

The point is, rest just has to return a sequence.  That sequence is lazy.  Therefore, (-> x rest rest rest) needs to process two values of x and then return the lazy sequence.  Hence, two dots.

next, on the other hand, has to return nil if there are no more elements in the sequence, so it's got to evaluate x a third time to determine whether or not the sequence was empty.  So three dots.

When you actually ask for the value, any remaining laziness needs to be discarded.  So, you get one more dot for rest.  The next version is done, so no more dots.

Comment: +1 for "next, on the other hand, has to return nil if there are no more elements in the sequence, so it's got to evaluate x a third time to determine whether or not the sequence was empty. So three dots."

Answer (score 1):

What is unanswered so far is why `next` is more *eager* than `rest` which is at the heart of the difference you describe. `next` returns `nil` for any list less than 2 in length. In contrast, `rest` returns the empty list in these scenarios. This suggest that when calling `next` on a list of 1 element we are implicitly done handling our sequence (in recursion for example) and thus we can safely assume it is time to realize the first element. That accounts for the early versus late realization of the final dot.

Answer (score 0):

`next` executes the `#()` function as soon as it is called, whereas `rest` does not because it does not have to yet - it waits as long as possible - so no realization/execution occurs in this example until another `rest` is called, or the value needs to be returned, which is the case when printing.

I too missed the dots on first reading. Only two dots for `rest` because there hasn't been a good enough reason (yet) for the last `rest` to be realized.